# Schema file in rails app wont update anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, schema

I have been running a few migrations and it doesnt update the schema file. I know the migrations have correctly changed my database but it seems my schema file wont change anymore... Here's my schema file. It misses the last table I have created (table 'notifications') and the several migrations I runned on this table.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150501141614) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "namespace"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree

  create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "owner_type"
    t.string   "key"
    t.text     "parameters"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "recipient_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "activities", ["owner_id", "owner_type"], name: "index_activities_on_owner_id_and_owner_type", using: :btree
  add_index "activities", ["recipient_id", "recipient_type"], name: "index_activities_on_recipient_id_and_recipient_type", using: :btree
  add_index "activities", ["trackable_id", "trackable_type"], name: "index_activities_on_trackable_id_and_trackable_type", using: :btree

  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "convocations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "hour"
    t.integer  "subscription_id"
    t.string   "status",          default: "pending"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "convocations", ["subscription_id"], name: "index_convocations_on_subscription_id", using: :btree

  create_table "mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "unsubscriber_id"
    t.string  "unsubscriber_type"
    t.integer "conversation_id"
  end

  add_index "mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs", ["conversation_id"], name: "index_mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs_on_conversation_id", using: :btree
  add_index "mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs", ["unsubscriber_id", "unsubscriber_type"], name: "index_mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs_on_unsubscriber_id_type", using: :btree

  create_table "mailboxer_conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "subject",    default: ""
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end

  create_table "mailboxer_notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "type"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "subject",              default: ""
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.string   "sender_type"
    t.integer  "conversation_id"
    t.boolean  "draft",                default: false
    t.string   "notification_code"
    t.integer  "notified_object_id"
    t.string   "notified_object_type"
    t.string   "attachment"
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.boolean  "global",               default: false
    t.datetime "expires"
  end

  add_index "mailboxer_notifications", ["conversation_id"], name: "index_mailboxer_notifications_on_conversation_id", using: :btree
  add_index "mailboxer_notifications", ["notified_object_id", "notified_object_type"], name: "index_mailboxer_notifications_on_notified_object_id_and_type", using: :btree
  add_index "mailboxer_notifications", ["sender_id", "sender_type"], name: "index_mailboxer_notifications_on_sender_id_and_sender_type", using: :btree
  add_index "mailboxer_notifications", ["type"], name: "index_mailboxer_notifications_on_type", using: :btree

  create_table "mailboxer_receipts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "receiver_id"
    t.string   "receiver_type"
    t.integer  "notification_id",                            null: false
    t.boolean  "is_read",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "trashed",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "deleted",                    default: false
    t.string   "mailbox_type",    limit: 25
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 null: false
  end

  add_index "mailboxer_receipts", ["notification_id"], name: "index_mailboxer_receipts_on_notification_id", using: :btree
  add_index "mailboxer_receipts", ["receiver_id", "receiver_type"], name: "index_mailboxer_receipts_on_receiver_id_and_receiver_type", using: :btree

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "read_at"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.integer  "convocation_id"
  end

  add_index "messages", ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "tournament_id"
    t.string   "status",        default: "pending"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
  end

  add_index "subscriptions", ["tournament_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_tournament_id", using: :btree
  add_index "subscriptions", ["user_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "genre"
    t.string   "category"
    t.boolean  "accepted"
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.date     "starts_on"
    t.date     "ends_on"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "club_organisateur"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end

  add_index "tournaments", ["user_id"], name: "index_tournaments_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "transfers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "mangopay_transaction_id"
    t.string   "category"
    t.json     "archive"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.integer  "tournament_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                               default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",                  default: ""
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                       default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "ranking"
    t.boolean  "judge",                               default: false
    t.string   "genre"
    t.string   "date_of_birth"
    t.string   "licence_number"
    t.integer  "judge_number"
    t.string   "invitation_token"
    t.datetime "invitation_created_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_accepted_at"
    t.integer  "invitation_limit"
    t.integer  "invited_by_id"
    t.string   "invited_by_type"
    t.integer  "invitations_count",                   default: 0
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "telephone"
    t.string   "picture_file_name"
    t.string   "picture_content_type"
    t.integer  "picture_file_size"
    t.datetime "picture_updated_at"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.string   "token"
    t.datetime "token_expiry"
    t.boolean  "admin",                               default: false, null: false
    t.string   "licencepicture_file_name"
    t.string   "licencepicture_content_type"
    t.integer  "licencepicture_file_size"
    t.datetime "licencepicture_updated_at"
    t.string   "certifmedpicture_file_name"
    t.string   "certifmedpicture_content_type"
    t.integer  "certifmedpicture_file_size"
    t.datetime "certifmedpicture_updated_at"
    t.string   "attestationformationja_file_name"
    t.string   "attestationformationja_content_type"
    t.integer  "attestationformationja_file_size"
    t.datetime "attestationformationja_updated_at"
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.integer  "mangopay_natural_user_id"
    t.integer  "wallet_id"
    t.integer  "kyc_document_id"
    t.integer  "card_id"
    t.datetime "birthdate"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["invitation_token"], name: "index_users_on_invitation_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["invitations_count"], name: "index_users_on_invitations_count", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["invited_by_id"], name: "index_users_on_invited_by_id", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "convocations", "subscriptions"
  add_foreign_key "mailboxer_conversation_opt_outs", "mailboxer_conversations", column: "conversation_id", name: "mb_opt_outs_on_conversations_id"
  add_foreign_key "mailboxer_notifications", "mailboxer_conversations", column: "conversation_id", name: "notifications_on_conversation_id"
  add_foreign_key "mailboxer_receipts", "mailboxer_notifications", column: "notification_id", name: "receipts_on_notification_id"
  add_foreign_key "subscriptions", "tournaments"
  add_foreign_key "subscriptions", "users"
  add_foreign_key "tournaments", "users"
end
```

I then ran rake db:drop db:create db:migrate but my schema file was still incomplete. I then tried to run another migration just to check:

```
class AddColumnClubToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_column :users, :club, :string
  end
end
```

but the schema file still wouldnt update

Answer (score 1):

Just rebuild DB in **development** use: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`. This command should drop DB and rebuild it from scratch include `schema.rb`.

If this is doesn't work then change your new migrations. Probably you have mistake (i.e. typo in method name, etc.).

Comment: if I do rake db:drop I will loose all my developpment db right ?

Comment: I did what you just said and cleared my database. My schema file is still incomplete. I tried to run a migration just to check and my schema file didnt update. I think the migration was ok :
`class AddColumnClubToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_column :users, :club, :string
  end
end
`